# How to implement a Bluetooth A2DP sink?

Tags: bluetooth, qt-mobility

I'm interested in implementing a a2dp audio sink.
The framework of choice so far for me is the bluetooth classes of Qt's QtMobility. I also heard a2dp is using l2cap.
Where can I get any more detailed specifications?

Answer (score 0):

You can get all the adopted bluetooth specifications here 
https://www.bluetooth.org/Technical/Specifications/adopted.htm
A2DP is part of this list.

I am not sure if QT provide you with the necessary APIs on l2cap to implement an a2dp sink by yourself.